# .NET 4.0 MVC 2 Blank Web APP option Un-Available

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

So I have downloaded the most recent version of Visual Studio 2010, and because no MVC 3 books are out, I am using Scott's MVC2 book. He has called for me to start a new project using an MVC 2 blank app, but I do not get the option to do so after I click " MVC 2 Web App"- it just creates the blue template. But, when I click MVC 3 I get the pop up dialogue which allows me to start an empty, populated, or another version of MVC 3.

I have uninstalled twice, and have looked for the template separately. I have been searching for two days, and I need help from the experts.

I am using Windows 7 ultimate 64 bit via bootcamp on 2009 macbook pro unibody if that helps/ matters.

Thank you SO MUCH in advance.

Ryan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `New Project -> Installed Templates -> Visual C# -> Web.` Now you will see the `ASP.NET MVC2 Empty Web application.` Use that to create your empty MVC2 application.

Comment: Made me wait 2 minutes for some reason.